# Ignore dates and abbreviations for splitting string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace

With this code I'm trying to split a string into sentences. This is nearly working, as abbreviations (always have the **fixed format** `s.s.`!) are handled like words, so there won't be a split after that.

But I also need this for dates, which are formated like `x.x.`, `xx.xx.`, `x.x.xx`... (always numbers!)

```
content = "This is a string with numbers (123.456,78 or 100.000), dates (01.01. or 1.2. or 1.02.16) and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn't split the sentence. dates and abbreviations should be ignored for splitting the string. So in this case, there are three sentences"

var result = content.replace(/\b(\w\.\w\.)|([.?!])\s+(?=[A-Za-z])/g, function(m, g1, g2){
    return g1 ? g1 : g2+"\r";
});
var arr = result.split("\r");
```

So I guess `\b(\w\.\w\.)` should be extended also for numbers, which could have one or two numbers in front of a point or two/four numbers as an optional year.

The result in this example should have three elements in the array.

Comment: Try adding an alternative, like `\b(\w\.\w\.|\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`.

Comment: Without an abbreviation list, it's impossible.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte This is simply wrong as both types are defined in this example exactly: abbr have the format `s.s.` (characters) and dates have the format `x.x.x.`(numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}\.?` alternative to the first part of the regex:

```js
content = "This is a string with numbers (123.456,78 or 100.000), dates (01.01. or 1.2. or 1.02.16) and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn't split the sentence. dates and abbreviations should be ignored for splitting the string. So in this case, there are three sentences"

var result = content.replace(/\b(\w\.\w\.|\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}\.?)|([.?!])\s+(?=[A-Za-z])/g, function(m, g1, g2){
    return g1 ? g1 : g2 + "\r";
});
var arr = result.split("\r");
document.body.innerHTML =  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

The `\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}\.?` subpattern matches:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits followed by...
- `(?:\.\d+){1,2}` - 1 or 2 sequences of a dot followed by one or more digits
- `\.?` - and an optional dot/

Comment: But year could have four digits

Comment: Then use `{1,3}` instead of `{1,2}`.